# Nulling variables of Fragment on onDestroy()

Tags: java, android, performance, android-fragments

Should I explicitely set all variables of fragment to null in onDestroy (or onDetach) method to avoid memory leaks? Or it is not necessary, and they will be GCed when fragment is "destroyed". What are the best practices? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to worry about this. The GC will take care of it. In Java you pretty much have to TRY to have a memory leak (yes, it's possible, but very rare). So, don't worry about it. If you do set the variables to `null` you would just end up wasting time on code you don't need, and would add to maintenance down the road. The GC in Java does a great job of destroy variables and objects that aren't referenced.

Comment: I managed to have a memory leak in an Android application (it crashed after a while because of OutOfMemoryError), where I had to loop through some objects and set some references to null to make life easier for the garbage collector. But a good rule of thumb is really: "Don't fix what isn't broken".

Comment: Yeah, I know they've happened before, and it's possible, but it's very rare. I agree though, don't fix what isn't broken :)

Comment: Just a tip : for detecting leaks, this library is very useful https://github.com/square/leakcanary

Answer (score 10):

Just add-on,

1. If you have any service running in your code, stop it.
2. If you have registered to any broadcast or any other listeners, unregister them
3. If you have any cursors open, close them.
4. If you have any bitmaps, recycle them.

Comment: good addition, thank you !